# MicrosoftOnline Bearer Token retrieval works on one server but not the other

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, bearer-token

I have a service that has been running successfully (and still is) on a Windows server for several years.

The customer wanted to double capacity so wish it to run on a second Windows server. However, it fails.

The part that is failing is the bearer token retrieval from Microsoft Online.

The second server has been confirmed to be able to do this in Soap UI

[image: SoapUI Success]

The crux of the reported exception is this

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. 
---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. 
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The client and server cannot communicate
, because they do not possess a common algorithm
```

The failing function is this - it is VB.NET (don't ask...)

```
    Public Async Function GenerateAccessToken(baseURL As String, authorization As String, clientID As String, clientSecret As String, resource As String) As Task(Of String)
        Dim responseString As String

        Try
            Dim client As HttpClient = HeadersForAccessTokenGenerate(baseURL, authorization)
            Dim body As String = ""

            Dim request As HttpRequestMessage = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, client.BaseAddress)
            request.Content = New StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

            Dim postData As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))()
            postData.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("grant_type", "client_credentials"))
            postData.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("client_id", clientID))
            postData.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("client_secret", clientSecret))
            postData.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("resource", resource))
            request.Content = New FormUrlEncodedContent(postData)

            Dim tokenResponse As HttpResponseMessage = client.PostAsync(baseURL, New FormUrlEncodedContent(postData)).Result

            responseString = Await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        Catch ex As HttpRequestException
            Throw ex
        End Try

        'Return If(responseString.Contains("error"), responseString, token.AccessToken)
        Return (responseString)
    End Function
```

Just to re-iterate - this code succeeds on one server but not another, and it works on both in SoapUI.

I am only at the level where I can ask the customer questions and do not have direct access to the servers and so I have to take the customer at their word that the servers are configured the same.

What things can I get them to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have solved this. I am unable to check with the customer for a while but putting in the line

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls13
```

reproduces their error on my development system, so I am guessing the the

System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault is actually different for both servers.

of all the possible values

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

is the one that makes it work again on my development PC.

I am posting this as it may help someone else.